# Cannot find column name in xvaluemember while creating chart

Tags: c#, database, charts

I tried linking my database to my chart, but when I am editing chart properties, out of the 21 total columns in my database only 11 are visible in the xvaluemember space. So cannot add my column to xvaluemember.

Tried doing it with code too, but didn't work.

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "AnimalIDAndStep";
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Volume 1";

        chart1.Series[1].XValueMember = "AnimalIDAndStep";
        chart1.Series[1].YValueMembers = "Volume 2";

        chart1.Series[2].XValueMember = "AnimalIDAndStep";
        chart1.Series[2].YValueMembers = "Volume 3";
```

below is the error message

[image]

Below is where the data is coming from

[image]

Below is the table definition

[image]

But check out how the chart properties is still not showing the column name AnimalIDAndStep

[image]

Comment: you should show where is your data coming from

Comment: @MorenajeRDHi, I have edited the question. Please take a look

Comment: Well that column seems to be missing from the DataSource. How come? What is the ds? A query? A c# ado DataTable?

Comment: Hi @TaW, pardon but that was French for me, I am a just a mechanical engineer trying to code an application for my instrument. Please explain, what is ado datable, how can I use it here? Why are almost ten columns missing from the datasource?

Comment: ADO is the most common way to access a database. One creates a DataTable and an SQL query and Fills the table from the database. Then one can bind controls to the table. Note the difference between the tables in the database and the DataTable in C#! What do you bind the chart/series to?

Comment: @TaW Hi, I tried and it worked. Thanks...